# How can I get the mode (=most frequent valuee) of a bunch of character values in R (rowwise)?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to get the rowwise mode from a bunch of character vectors within a tibble:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)

test_data <- tibble(a_1 = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                    b_1 = c(1:10),
                    a_2 = sample(c("a", "b"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                    c_1 = c(11:20),
                    a_3 = sample(c("b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                    d_1 = c(21:30),
                    a_4 = sample(c("b", "c", NA), 10, replace = TRUE))
```

I found a function for getting the mode online:

```
getmode <- function(v) {
  uniqv <- unique(v)
  uniqv[which.max(tabulate(match(v, uniqv)))]
}
```

When I try to implement this with tidyverse Syntax:

```
test_data %>% mutate(Mode_a = getmode(c_across(starts_with("a_"))))
```

I do not get the desired result (e.g. Mode_a for row 2 should be "a", for row 9 it should be "c"):

```
# A tibble: 10 x 8
   a_1     b_1 a_2     c_1 a_3     d_1 a_4   Mode_a
   <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> 
 1 a         1 b        11 b        21 NA    b     
 2 a         2 a        12 b        22 c     b     
 3 a         3 a        13 c        23 b     b     
 4 a         4 b        14 b        24 c     b     
 5 b         5 b        15 b        25 c     b     
 6 b         6 b        16 b        26 NA    b     
 7 b         7 b        17 b        27 NA    b     
 8 a         8 a        18 c        28 c     b     
 9 c         9 a        19 c        29 c     b     
10 c        10 a        20 c        30 c     b
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `rowwise()` in your pipe. Now your `tidyverse` solution should work!

```
df <- test_data %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Mode_a = getmode(c_across(starts_with("a_"))))
```

Comment: Thank You, that's slightly embarassing, given I did add rowwise to the title of my question...

Answer (score 2):

You can use apply in base R:

```r
set.seed(42)

test_data <- data.frame(a_1 = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                b_1 = c(1:10),
                a_2 = sample(c("a", "b"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                c_1 = c(11:20),
                a_3 = sample(c("b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                d_1 = c(21:30),
                a_4 = sample(c("b", "c", NA), 10, replace = TRUE))

test_data$mode <- apply(test_data,1,function(x) names(which.max(table(x))))

test_data
#>    a_1 b_1 a_2 c_1 a_3 d_1  a_4 mode
#> 1    a   1   b  11   b  21 <NA>    b
#> 2    a   2   a  12   b  22    c    a
#> 3    a   3   a  13   c  23    b    a
#> 4    a   4   b  14   b  24    c    b
#> 5    b   5   b  15   b  25    c    b
#> 6    b   6   b  16   b  26 <NA>    b
#> 7    b   7   b  17   b  27 <NA>    b
#> 8    a   8   a  18   c  28    c    a
#> 9    c   9   a  19   c  29    c    c
#> 10   c  10   a  20   c  30    c    c
```

And if the numbers in the columns are unique there is no need to exclude them. I believe if there is a tie the function will pick the first element (a character in this case).

If you want to select the columns you can of course build this into the apply function as well:

```r
set.seed(42)

test_data <- data.frame(a_1 = sample(c("a", "b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                b_1 = c(1:10),
                a_2 = sample(c("a", "b"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                c_1 = c(11:20),
                a_3 = sample(c("b", "c"), 10, replace = TRUE),
                d_1 = c(21:30),
                a_4 = sample(c("b", "c", NA), 10, replace = TRUE))

test_data$mode <- apply(test_data[seq(1, ncol(test_data), by = 2)],1,function(x) names(which.max(table(x))))

test_data
#>    a_1 b_1 a_2 c_1 a_3 d_1  a_4 mode
#> 1    a   1   b  11   b  21 <NA>    b
#> 2    a   2   a  12   b  22    c    a
#> 3    a   3   a  13   c  23    b    a
#> 4    a   4   b  14   b  24    c    b
#> 5    b   5   b  15   b  25    c    b
#> 6    b   6   b  16   b  26 <NA>    b
#> 7    b   7   b  17   b  27 <NA>    b
#> 8    a   8   a  18   c  28    c    a
#> 9    c   9   a  19   c  29    c    c
#> 10   c  10   a  20   c  30    c    c
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank You, but I actually wanted the mode just for the columns, containing characters. Numbers might be not unique. Sorry, my example did not account for that.